# Dismiss dictionary popover controller in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uipopovercontroller

How to dismiss the default dictionary popover (it comes from textview or textfield)

Now i want to dismiss the popover(dictionary) when the app is minimized(background mode)[image]

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: do you mean automatic words listing option. then set auto correction type as UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo for textview or textfield.

Comment: No. It is "Define" options in text selection

Comment: I have this need also. "App Programming Guide for iOS" says: "Clean up resources for active alerts when moving to the background... It is up to you to provide the appropriate cleanup behavior... For example, you might want to cancel the action sheet or alert view programmatically..." I'd love to, I just can't find a "legal" way for the Dictionary or other system UI (data detection invoked actionSheet). Why? My app supports openURL which moves the user to a place in the app based on a URL tap. I would like to dismiss irrelevant system UI before I navigate my app to the place the URL indicates.